# How to render images from backend to frontend in mern stack

Tags: javascript, reactjs, multer, mern

Here, I'm trying to render images that are in backend/uploads/images.`

this is my backend server.js file

```html
const express = require("express");
require("dotenv").config();
const cors = require("cors");
const { v4: uuidv4 } = require("uuid");
const app = express();
const postRoute = require("./routes/postRoute");
const userRoute = require("./routes/userRoute");
const DbConnection = require("./db/db");

DbConnection();
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.static("uploads/images"));

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("Home server");
});

app.use("/api", postRoute);
app.use("/api/users", userRoute);
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 5000, () => {
  console.log("Server started");
});
```

`

this is my ui where i want to pull the image as title("hello") and content("sadsaassa") is being pulled from mongodb.
[image]

this is how i tried to pull the image
<img
src={`../../../../backend/uploads/images/${detailedArticle?.imageUrl}`}
/>
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Since Nodejs and Reactjs are running in different server, you have to access images over http something like this..

```
http://localhost:5000/{image}.png
```

Comment: can you help me with it?

Comment: Can you print ``detailedArticle.imageUrl`` here?  It should be the file name.

Comment: 7c1d83fbe2bc6593cebab98c714e6da8.jpeg it is like this

Answer (score 0):

You can not access it from the local directory as you are saving the image using NodeJS.

If you are trying to access on local machine where your node server is also running then use

> http://localhost:3000/server/public/upload/{image}

If you are trying to access the image from already deployed node application then use

> http://abchost:3000/server/public/upload/{image}

Comment: I tried this but didnt work  <img src={`http://localhost:8000/${detailedArticle.imageUrl}`} />

Comment: Can you please let me know your node URL and exact path of the assets folder where your images are store towards nodeJS.

Answer (score 0):

Create an API in backend:

```
app.use('/images', express.static('uploads/images'));
```

and frontend code is:

```html
<img src={`/images/${product.image}`} alt={product.name} />
```

Answer (score 0):

***Instead of local host use ip number that will solve your error***

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).